# expo-facebook not tracking all app install events

Tags: facebook, expo, fbsdk

We have installed expo-facebook to our app to track app installs from Facebook Ads. Currently, only about 20% of the new app installs are recorded in Facebook AppEvents analytics, where all app installs should appear whether they come from Facebook ads or not. We also track them with Google Analytics and from App Store and Google Play, so it’s clear that the issue is with expo-facebook/Facebook SDK. We ask for user consent to track the app installs before initializing Facebook with automatic event tracking enabled, but most of the users give their consent.

- SDK Version: 40
- Android and iOS
- expo-facebook

This is how we initialize Facebook and it seems to work, as some events do come through and no errors are thrown with this solution:

```
try {
  await Facebook.initializeAsync({
    appId: ‘OUR_APP_ID’,
    appName: ‘OUR_APP_NAME’,
    autoLogAppEvents: true
  })
} catch ({ message }) {
  captureException(message)
}
```

Has anyone else had this issue and come up with a solution? Ejecting to a bare workflow is not an option here.

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this? We are seeing the same issue, @matias

Comment: Still looking for an answer, and nowhere to be found :(